# Java, 15/6 equation returning 2.0?

Tags: java, division

I'm beginning to think my brain is playing a cruel joke on me, **why on earth is 15/6 returning 2.0**?

You can test here, http://ideone.com/xUaYEF.

```
    double average = 15/6;
    System.out.println("value: "+average);
```

And everytime, the output is,

```
value: 2.0
```

Last I checked with a calculator and google **15/6 is 2.5**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double average = 15/6.0;
```

Division of int by int will return an int. That is why you get 2. Then, as you declared it as a double, it would add the .0 at the end.

If you divide a double by double (15/6.0, 15.0/6, or 15.0/6.0) it will come out as a double.